# Group R table entries by month

Tags: r, plot

I have as CSV value with two columns, a unix timestamp and a version string. What I finally want to achieve is to group the data by months and plot the data, so that the single months are entries on the x axis, and a line is plotted for each unique version string, where the y axis values should represent the number of hits on that month.

Here is a small example CSV:

```
timestamp,version
1434974143,1.0.0
1435734004,1.1.0
1435734304,1.0.0
1435735386,1.2.0
```

I'm new to R, so I encountered several problems. First I successfully read the csv with

```
mydata <- read.csv("data.csv")
```

and figured out an ungly function that convers a single timestamp into an R date:

```
as_time <- function(val){
    return(head(as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(val)),origin="1970-01-01",tz="GMT")))
}
```

But non of the several *apply* functions seemed to work on the table column.

So how do I create a data structure, that groups the version hits by month, and can be plotted later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier than you think!

You are essentially looking for the `hist` function.

```
#Let's make some mock data    
# Set the random seed for reproducibility
set.seed(12345)

my.data <- data.frame(timestamp = runif(1000, 1420000000, 1460000000), 
                      version = sample(1:5, 1000, replace = T))

my.data$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(my.data$timestamp, origin = "1970-01-01")

# Histogram of the data, irrespective of version
hist(my.data$timestamp, "month")

# If you want to see the version then split the data first...
my.data.split <- split(my.data, my.data$version)
# Then apply hist
counts <- sapply(my.data.split, function (x)
  {
  h <- hist(x$timestamp, br = "month", plot = FALSE)
  h$counts
  })

# Transform into a matrix and plot
counts <- do.call("rbind", counts)  
barplot(counts, beside = T)
```

Comment: thank you, looks great, I would not have expected that it is that easy to apply the as.POSIXct function.. But how can I extract the version distribution per month from the hist data?

Comment: @muffel ah, I didn't see that part, just a sec, I'll update the answer

Comment: @muffel updated, now counts holds the counts for each version (I used 1:5 as version numbers as an example, but that's irrelevant)

Comment: I see a warning in your second construction of `counts`, fyi: "number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length"

Comment: @nico: IMO, the way you get counts by version/month is unnecessarily complex. `xtabs()` is your friend :-). See my comment to jeremycg.

Comment: @DagHjermann I did it that way because initially I didn't see he wanted to split by version, so it was just a one-liner using hist. But, please, do add an `xtabs` example as well, the more solution we add the better the question is answered :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `as.yearmon` function from the `zoo` package to get year/month formats:

```
library(zoo)
dat$yearmon <- as.yearmon(as.POSIXct(dat$timestamp, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT"))
```

Then it depends what you want to do with your data. For example, number of version hits per month (thanks to @Frank for fixing):

```
dat %>% group_by(yearmon, version) %>%
         summarise(hits = n())
```

Comment: great, thank you! just two questions: what is `%>%` doing? I haven't seen this before (but am just a beginner in R). The output of summarise is great, but could this somehow be plotted?

Comment: the `%>%` is the pipe from he `magrittr` and `dplyr` packages - it takes the output and uses it as the first argument to the next function, so you don't have to nest a million functions see [the cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf)

Comment: To plot, set the output of the above to be x, then use library(ggplot2), then ggplot(x, aes(x = factor(yearmon), y = versions)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")

Comment: The classical (non-magrittr, non-dplyr) way to tabulate the data would be `mytable <- xtabs(~yearmon + version, dat)`, or if you for instance want to plot the data using ggplot2, `mytable <- as.data.frame(xtabs(~yearmon + version, dat))`. Then you can plot it by `ggplot(mytable, aes(x = yearmon, y=Freq, colour=version))  + geom_line()`.